# Microsoft visual studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework tools error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, ado.net

[image]

Hey anytime I start up visual studio i get an error popping up in relation to the title of this post.

The error message says enter a path to `ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu.msi`. In the use source box it says

> c:\users\conor\appdata\local\temp\rar$exa0.270\wcu\eftools\

but there is no folder when trying to locate it.  Can anyone help ?

Comment: Could you please share the error window which is coming? I mean I want to see the exact error window which is coming?

Comment: Can you add a image with stack ovewrflow and il do a print screen ?

Comment: Yes you can surely add an image.

Comment: Just edit your question and above the box you will find the link to upload image for your question.

Comment: Have you tried repairing your VS install ?

Comment: I added the image. @Nacereddine  I havent yet because i am installing the service pack so that i can use Windows app dev kit.

Comment: @Pendo826 You can find the package that the installer is looking for on your VS2010 DVD in `<DVD Drive Letter or VS ISO image>\WCU\EFTools\ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu.msi`. Once it installs this package it should get rid of the error message.

Comment: I cant find the package anywhere ive checked my whole c drive :S

Comment: I guess ill just have to reinstall it.

Comment: @Pendo826 Not your `C:` Drive but your installation DVD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When downloaded from Microsoft Dreamsparks, like i did.  The software installer creates a temp folder on the c drive.  this is what the program was looking for.  The reason it could not find it because it was downloaded on another pc.  Which means the temp folder was never created.

Comment: I don't think that a sane program can rely on the existence of some old temporary files.